# ef code first conditional mapping

Tags: entity-framework

Is there a way to do conditional mapping in EF 6 with Code First.

We have a table called Entity which holds Suppliers, Customers and Employees. There is a flag field which identifies if a record is supplier, customer, employee or a combination of them. So we are using enum flags. In our code we have three domain objects (Supplier, Customer and Employee). I want to map these objects to the Entity table based on the flag field. Can somebody please tell me if this is possible in EF6. Please note that we are using Code First

Comment: How close is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671460/entityframework-code-first-inheritance-with-custom-discriminator) to what you want to accomplish?

Comment: The difference in my case is that I have one table - Entity which holds all different types of Entities (Supplier, Customer and Employee). So I don't think the two problems are related

Comment: Do the Supplier, Customer and Employee classes derive from a common class?

Comment: Yes they derive from the Entity class

Comment: the description, isnt consistent to me.  but sounds like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292 is requried

Comment: @phil. The link you provided is not for code first. We are using code first

Comment: sorry, this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#2.4